# Why can't I compile an own created library on PlatformIO?

Tags: esp32

I've been trying to figure out why PlatformIO is throwing me the next error:

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\esp32dev\firmware.elf] Error 1

The previous text to this error is in yellow, indicating:
undefined reference to `newlibXD::newlibXD()'  dir in function` _GLOBAL__sub_I_xd': dir: undefined reference to `newlibXD::newlibXD()

my code (this is a test code, because I wanted to solve it for the original, but same issue:
main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "newlibXD.h"
newlibXD xd;

void setup() 
{

}

void loop() 
{
  
}
```

newlibXD.h:

```
#ifndef newlibXD_h
#define newlibXD_h
    #include <Arduino.h>

    class newlibXD
    {
        private:
            int var;
        public:
            newlibXD();
            void genFunc();
    };
#endif
```

newlibXD.cpp

```
#include "newlibXD.h"

newlibXD::newlibXD()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void newlibXD::genFunc()
{
    
}
```

and my platformio.ini

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

What I've tried: trying on new code (this example), trying on new project, trying on different configurations, for example:
same issue, but warning now as:
undefined reference to `newlibXD::genFunc()' dir: in function` setup()': dir: undefined reference to `newlibXD::genFunc()'

main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "newlibXD.h"
newlibXD xd;

void setup() 
{
  xd.genFunc();
}

void loop() 
{

}
```

and in newlibXD.h and .cpp I removed the constructor.

This is so weird for me, since I've never had this problem before, and maybe I'm missing something or is it just an issue with PlatformIO, anyone has any idea?

trying on new code (this example), trying on new project, trying on different configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Nah, just tried and it compiles fine on my Mac. The only assumption I've made is that your newlibXD.h & newlibXD.cpp files are in the "lib > newlibXD" folder

PlatformIO can be pissy with the project's paths, you sure you don't have some non-ASCII characters somewhere in your projects path something like letter "é" or similar in the name of any folder leading to your project? Basically have you tried compiling from somewhere like C:\test\

I would also run a full clean: Pltaformio icon in the side bar (little alien face) > Project Tasks > Full clean
If that doesn't work then manually delete everything in the projects folder > .pio

Mind you, it could also be the ESP32 firmware files, had that before and had to re-install the ESP32 platform.

I would start from a fresh new project in the C:\test\ and call everything test (test.h, test.cpp), lowercase, no spaces and see what happens :-)

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.
As you mentioned, I had it in a folder with an "í", but also I tried the part on starting a new project.
As well, it isn't in the "lib" folder, they're on "include".
I made the full clean and firmware reinstallation as well, but the issue seems to continue.
I also made it in a different pc, so... I don't know, maybe it's an issue on Windows?

Comment: As far as I know, private libraries should be in some folder that goes into the "lib" folder (can't just have .h &.cpp in the "lib" root), that's what I've been doing for years. There's a few video tutorials on my website with my library code for download so you can compare things (chipchop.io), if that doesn't compile on the ESP than it's definitely something funky with your PC/PlatformIO setup.

Comment: So... Just to let you know, I've found what the problem was.
In include folder I had the header and its cpp, And the main in src.
I moved the header's cpp to src and it worked.

Comment: Hey, that's great to hear! Good luck with your library :-)